# Confusion on finding $y$ in $y^2=x^2$

Tags: real-analysis

If $y^2=x^2$, then $y=\pm x$ or $y=\pm \mid x\mid$, I am really confused!!!

I have a feeling that both of them are true. But intuition is not enough I guess. Need justification.

Comment: By definition, $|x| = x$ if $x \ge 0$, and $-x$ if $x < 0$.  Thus $\pm x = \mp |x|$.  Is that the confusion?

Comment: They are both true. All $3$ result in the same plot on a graph. The latter two: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/phv3axykg6, https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2fe7uxjupq

Comment: @XanderHenderson you are right, that was the confution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I often find it helpful to rewrite equations like $$y^2=x^2$$ as $$y^2-x^2=(y+x)(y-x)=0$$

Then one of the two factors must be zero i.e. $y+x=0$ or $y-x=0$ that is $y=-x$ or $y=x$, which we express as $y=\pm x$

If instead we take the square root directly with the convention that the principal value of the square root is positive we get $y=|x|$. Of course we know that there is also a negative solution $y=-|x|$, and if we want both we put $y=\pm |x|$.

These two ways of addressing the problem give two different expressions for the answer, but the answers are two different ways of expressing the same thing. If $x\gt 0$ we have $x=|x|, -x=-|x|$ and if $x\lt 0$ it is $x=-|x|, -x=|x|$.

If $y=x=0$ we have just one value. But that special case clearly doesn't cause a problem.

Comment: so what I was thinking is right, isn't?

Comment: Indeed, both are true.

Comment: but James is saying $y=\pm |x|$ is false!

Comment: @doctorme I think James is wrong, and there were some poor and confusing answers and comments. I have explained what I think in enough detail, I hope, that it is clear why I think this.

Comment: thanks, I actully asking you because yours is perfectly written

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

both are true since 
$$y^2=x^2=|x|^2$$
and

$$y^2=x^2\implies (y-x)(y+x)=0$$
and $$(y+|x|)(y-|x|)=0$$

thus
$y=\pm x$ or $y=\pm |x|$.

Comment: Thanks, this is very clear.

Answer (score 1):

$0=y^2-x^2=(y-x)(y+x)$ implies that $y-x=0$ or $y+x=0$ or equivalently that $y=x$ or $y=-x$.

You could write the solution as: $$y\in\{-x,x\}\text{ or abbreviated }y=\pm x$$

Also we have $\{-x,x\}=\{-|x|,|x|\}$ so another way of writing the solution is: $$y\in\{-|x|,|x|\}\text{ or abbreviated }y=\pm |x|$$

Answer (score 0):

If $x^2=y^2$ thus $(x-y)(x+y)=0$ so $x=\pm y$

Jet the second equation has the same solution (draw a graph).